# Swift 2 Error: Solve "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift, dictionary

I would like store permutations of shuffled array in a Dictionary who takes my custom array list in key and the number of permutations in value and I have the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

How can I solve that ?

There's an example of my code

```
 func countPermutation() {
    var count: Int = 0
    let arrayCopy: [T] = self.data
    var shuffled: [T] = self.data
    var array = Array(count: 100, repeatedValue: [T]())
    var myMap: Dictionary<MyArray<T>, Int> = Dictionary()

    for var i = 0; i < 100; i++ {
        shuffled = shuffle(arrayCopy)
        array[i] = shuffled
    }

    let anyArray: AnyObject = array as! AnyObject
    let anyCopy: AnyObject = shuffled as! AnyObject

    for var j = 0; j < array.count; j++ {
        if anyArray[j].isEqual(anyCopy) {
            count++
            myMap = [anyCopy: count]
        }
    }

    print(myMap)
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't cast `anyCopy` to `AnyObject` since you need `myMap` to be a dictionary of type `[MyArray<T>: Int]`.

Answer (score 0):

You see such expression when Xcode does not understand what type do you want to have. I think now you have such problem because of non-obvious type of you shuffled variable. Try to be more explicit about types.

Comment: So, how can I solve the error ? I specified the type of my variables and Xcode display the error again..

Comment: to give you more detail answer need more code as well and I can try to make the same pros to find it out

Comment: I did: `myMap: [MyArray<T>: Int] += [anyCopy: count]
` And now i have the error "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'"